# File path set in File field does not show up in hook_node_insert

Tags: hooks, files, uri

I have a content type called project which has a File Field.  Inside this File Field I have set the File Path to be "project".

I have also created a custom module that implements hook_node_insert.  Inside this implementation I am printing the path to my log as so:

```
watchdog('node path','Node Path= ' . file_create_url($file->uri));
```

but when I look in my log I see this:

```
Node Path= http://localhost:8888/sites/default/files/Bubble%20Sort_6.zip
```

instead of  what I might hope for:

```
Node Path= http://localhost:8888/sites/default/files/project/Bubble%20Sort_6.zip
```

The file is correctly created inside the relative directory "project" but the path I get from hook_node_insert does not include this relative path.  Once again confused.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you figure this out? Also, my watchdog calls aren't working inside hook_node_insert()